# Why won't my suitescript deploy scripts fire?

Tags: netsuite

I don't know when this started, but I think it happened after I did some refactoring using the IDE with renaming.

Anyway, if I attach the script through the form, they fire. However, my user event, nor client scripts fire though there is a deployment record. That deployment record uses the same script that works IF it is attached via the form custom code area.

What happened?

EDIT:

For Instance:

Trying to add a button to opportunity:

```
function userEventBeforeLoad(type, form, request){
  var list = form.getSubList("item");
  list.addButton('custpage_customconfigurebutton', 'Configure', 'clientStartConfigurator()');
}
```

Upload Script

[image]

Add to "Script"

[image]

Deploy:

[image]

It never fires when I "Create Opportunity"?
NONE of my user event scripts are firing

EDIT 2 (NEW SCREENS as requested

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you provide screendumps of the "Scripts" tab of the Script record, and one of the Script Deployment record?

Answer (score 0):

Following lines of code working for me

```
function userEventBeforeLoad(type, form, request) {
        //nlapiLogExecution('error', 'type', type);
        var list = form.getSubList("item");
        list.addButton('custpage_customconfigurebutton', 'Configure',"alert('Hello World')");
}
```

I suspect you might have an error in your `clientStartConfigurator()`. To verify, you can also use the browser console on click of your button to see whether you're successfully returning from your respective function or not.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: It just won't fire. No button gets shown. All this use to work until I refactored my scripts, renamed some, etc. But now the ONLY scripts that will fire are the ones I add to Custom Form --> Custom Code. ??